# OpenMP 4.0 - GCC 5.2.0 - Overlap device and host task execution

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, hardware-acceleration, xeon-phi

I am trying to test a very simple program that uses gcc 5 offload capabilities through OpenMP 4.0 directives. My goal is to write a two independent tasks program with one task being executed on an accelerator (i.e. Intel MIC emulator) and another one being executed concurrently on the CPU.

Here's the code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define limit 100000

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int cpu_prime, acc_prime;

    #pragma omp task shared(acc_prime)
    {
            #pragma omp target map(tofrom: acc_prime)
            {
                    printf("mjf-dbg >> acc computation\n");
                    int i, j;
                    acc_prime=0;
                    for(i=0; i<limit; i++){
                            for(j=2; j<=i; j++){
                                    if(i%j==0)
                                            break;
                            }
                            if(j==i)
                                    acc_prime = i;
                    }
                    printf("mjf-dbg << acc computation\n");
            }
    }

    #pragma omp task shared(cpu_prime)
    {
            int i, j;
            cpu_prime=0;
            printf("mjf-dbg >> cpu computation\n");
            for(i=0; i<limit; i++){
                    for(j=2; j<=i; j++){
                            if(i%j==0)
                                    break;
                    }
                    if(j==i)
                            cpu_prime = i;
            }
            printf("mjf-dbg << cpu computation\n");
    }

    #pragma omp taskwait

    printf("cpu prime: %d \n", cpu_prime);
    printf("gpu prime: %d \n", acc_prime);

}
```

With this code I was expecting the following execution flow:

1. The Master Thread (MT) encounter the first explicit task region, bind to that task and begin its execution.
2. Encountering the target directive the MT offload the target block to the accelerator and reach a scheduling point
3. The MT go back to the implicit task region
4. The MT encounters the second explicit task region, bind to that task and begin its execution.
5. The MT performs the computation on host in parallel with the computation offloaded to the accelerator device.
6. The MT go back to the implicit task region and reach a scheduling point caused by the taskwait directive
7. The MT go back to the first explicit task region waiting for the end of the offloaded block.

Compile & Run:

```
gcc -fopenmp -foffload="-march=knl" overlap.c -o overlap
OFFLOAD_EMUL_RUN="sde -knl --" ./overlap
```

Output:

```
mjf-dbg >> acc computation
mjf-dbg << acc computation
mjf-dbg >> cpu computation
mjf-dbg << cpu computation
cpu prime: 99991 
gpu prime: 99991
```

This is not the output I was expecting, since it means that the master thread is waiting for the offload computation to be completed before scheduling the host task. Instead I was looking for something like this:

```
mjf-dbg >> acc computation
mjf-dbg >> cpu computation
mjf-dbg << cpu computation
mjf-dbg << acc computation
cpu prime: 99991 
gpu prime: 99991
```

The offload emulator is working properly since during the execution I can see the _offload_target process going to 100% CPU usage when the program is executing the target block.

So the question is: does anyone have any idea about why the two tasks are being serialized and not executed in parallel (one on host process and the other on the _offload_target emulation process)??

Comment: My guess is that it's an implementation issue. You might want to report this as a bug to GCC.

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the comment, I'll consider to file a bug if no one is able to explain me the behavior I'm observing. Would you be able to run this simple test on real hardware (maybe is an emulation issue)? I wish I could do that but right now I do not have access to a machine with a real Intel MIC. Thanks

Comment: Why can't you run it on KNC? Lots of those machines are available to users.

Comment: Yes I would like to do so if only I could have a real KNC, for the time being I have to stick to the emulator because I do not have a real hardware to test my code on :(

Comment: @Jeff GCC doesn't support code generation for KNC.

Comment: @IlyaVerbin You are definitely right, I would need a KNL to test the code on real hardware.

Comment: That's not quite true. The GNU/Linux toolchain of KNC is built with GCC. KNC supports Pentium x86 plus extensions. Union of KNC and Xeon ISAs is still x86. Of course, GCC doesn't support KNC VPU, but you can leverage C ABI standardization to mix in code built with ICC into GCC programs.

Comment: And since one of the best features of KNL is that it is available as a self-hosted socket, I'm not sure why you're so focused on KNL offload with GCC. What do you really want to accomplish?

Comment: @Jeff You're talking about special version of GCC in MPSS. However, GCC 5.2.0, trunk and all other versions don't support -march=knc.

Comment: @IlyaVerbin does GCC not support Pentium x86 that works on KNC?

Comment: @Jeff You can't just compile a program with `-march=pentium` and run it on KNC, because KNC requires special `e_machine` value in the ELF header (`EM_K1OM`).

Answer (score 1):

There's a more fundamental (and simpler) issue here than the offloading - your tasks aren't in a parallel region.

[OpenMP tasks have to be in a parallel region](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenMP/Tasks), even though they're typically then embedded in an `omp single`.

So this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

#pragma omp task 
    {
        printf("task 1 starts\n");
        sleep(3);
        printf("task 1 ends\n");
    }

#pragma omp task 
    {
        printf("task 2 starts\n");
        sleep(1);
        printf("task 2 ends\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Runs the tasks serially:

```
$ gcc -fopenmp brokentasks.c -o brokentasks
$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2

$ ./brokentasks 
task 1 starts
task 1 ends
task 2 starts
task 2 ends
```

Whereas putting the tasks in a parallel region like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
    {
#pragma omp task 
        {
            printf("task 1 starts\n");
            sleep(3);
            printf("task 1 ends\n");
        }

#pragma omp task 
        {
            printf("task 2 starts\n");
            sleep(1);
            printf("task 2 ends\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Works as expected

```
$ gcc -fopenmp tasks.c -o tasks
jdursi@odw-jdursi:~/tmp$ ./tasks
task 2 starts
task 1 starts
task 2 ends
task 1 ends
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I would say that it does not really answer my question which was all about offloading. Of course if I put my tasks within a parallel region with at least 2 threads then things are going more or less as expected. More or less! Indeed each thread is executing a task so I see the expected output but still the thread executing the offload task is waiting for the device to complete its job. This is unexpected to me, the thread should reach a scheduling point right after the target directive. Otherwise I always need double the number of threads to overlap device/host tasks.

Comment: @MaJac89 - Yes, your question is about offloading, but you're using OpenMP to do it, and the task pragmas are going to be ignored outside of a parallel region; offloading doesn't change this.  For offloading in particular, it's the "encountering task" that executes the target clause; there needs to be a thread bound to the the target construct.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it again (I already tried to enclose everything in a parallel region and the result goes as follow: with 1 thread the behavior is the same as I posted with serial execution, with 2 threads each thread is executing a task but the thread executing the offload part does wait until the device has finished its job and this is the thing I cannot understand). However I will edit the code as soon as I can so that I can better explain my point.

Comment: @MaJac89 OpenMP 4.0 says "The task that encounters the target construct waits at the end of the construct until execution of the region completes." Looks like you need OpenMP 4.1 with `omp target nowait` clause.

Comment: @IlyaVerbin Yes, I understand that but later in the OpenMP 4.0 specs when they write about Task scheduling you can read: "Task scheduling points are implied at the following locations: [...] the point immediately following the generation of a target region". Therefore I would expect that a thread encountering a target region is suspending the execution of its current task switching to the execution of an other one (if another independent task is available). Moreover take a look at these refs. [1](https://goo.gl/heZhRK) [2](http://goo.gl/h2DGRC) [3](http://goo.gl/S86Wnr) and look for 'async'.